# How to take screenshot in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way or package that can help either taking fullscreen screenshot, or screenshot of widget that is wrapped or at least sharing the picture of screen via native share option?

There are some packages and I have tried, did not found any useful one.

Comment: please post the package you used, to avoid any redundant recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RepaintBoundary** is the Widget you're looking for, this one can be converted into an image.

Example:

```
Future<CaptureResult> captureImage() async {
    final pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    final boundary = _boundaryKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
    final data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return CaptureResult(data.buffer.asUint8List(), image.width, image.height);
}

final _boundaryKey = GlobalKey();

RepaintBoundary(
   key: _boundaryKey,
   child: Container(),// Your Widgets to be captured.
)
```

Link: [**capture_widget.dart**](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/8eeadd8028c373df87f3a47bd4a35e36)

Comment: How to handle exceptions here? Is it possible to use this code in try catch block?

Comment: @Mahesh you can definitely use a try-catch block, you probably wouldn't need it in my opinion as the app just converts those device pixels to image.